# How does perfmon handle merging data when timestamps don't lineup

Tags: powershell, perfmon

Consider a situation where you have server01 which started perfmon at 15:55:15 to log data every 15 seconds. Then there is also server02 logging same counters with same frequency of 15 seconds, but it started at 15:55:20.

Now the perfmon data of both of these servers will never lineup exactly because of the 5 second time mismatch.

My question is, if you import logfiles from these two servers in perfmon, and try to combine the data in a single file, by saving as blg/csv or if you use powershell and do
$Data = ".\server01.blg" , "server02.blg" | Import-counter

How does perfmon/powershell fill in the blanks for timestamps where server01 has a data point but server02 doesn't have a data point, and vice versa.

To clarify, if you load both of the blg files in perfmon and save as csv, the csv will have both timestamps 15:55:15 and 15:55:20 and it will also include values for both servers for those timestampts. My question is whatis the mechanism of perfmon to fill in those blanks? Because it didn't log a value for server01 at 15:55:20, but in the merged csv, there is a value for server01.

I couldn't find this info anywhere about this mechanism.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it just shows a blank gap on the line chart for that particular server for the time period that is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm sorry that didn't answer my question. I edited the question to clarify it more.